# PHP mcrypt_decrypt will return garbage data when I tried to alter the encrypted text

Tags: php, encryption

How can I detect if a variable contains garbage?

I have encrypted text generated from `mcrypt_encrypt()`. I attempt to edit this (assuming that someone will alter the encrypted text). I want to return an empty value after decryption instead of something like `"Ú0úà¡ßQ9õ÷rŒi¾¼v’Ó}çTc~Žk"`

Comment: We can't help you. You haven't shown your code. But if you get garbage back, then something is wrong with your code. You ARE decrypting your cyphertext. But either the cyphertext and/or the key you're using are bad somehow, causing "garbage" - it's properly decoded, but you're decoding the wrong thing.

Comment: @marcB : Thank you for replying. The original text will be decrypted successfully if the encrypted text is not altered or adding/removing  characters. My problem is, how can I detect if the decryption returns a junnk data/garbage data.

Comment: crypt/decrypt is just a mathematical transform. if you "encrypt" by adding `1` to all the values, but accidentially decrypt by subtracting 2, it's not the algorithm's job to detect that. you can embed a sentinel value in the plaintext and see if that's present after the full cycle. e.g. "foo123" -> crypted text -> decrypted text". If the decrypted text starts with "foo", then you can be reasonably sure that "123" is what was encrypted to begin with.

Comment: @marcB : Is there a way that I can only check the return value? I mean , I'll validate the returned value if it is valid characters not a garbage data? Thanks by the way, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for a way of encrypting data in such a way that it will be possible to detect if anyone has tampered with it.

The easiest way to achieve this would be to incorporate a checksum into the data before you encrypt it.

For example, you could encrypt the data as follows:

```
$plaintext = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
$hash = md5($plaintext);
$output = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(CIPHER, KEY, $hash.$plaintext, MODE));
```

and then the decryption process would look like this:

```
$input = mcrypt_decrypt(CIPHER, KEY, base64_decode($output, MODE));
$hash = substr($input, 0, 32);
$text = substr($input, 32);
if (md5($text) != $hash) {
   die("Invalid data");
}
/* If you get this far, the encrypted data is fine */
  :
echo $text;
  :
```

Comment: Good read on Crypto.SE: [Should we MAC-then-encrypt or encrypt-then-MAC?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac)